# How to avoid getting captcha error when requesting POST using okhttp

Tags: java, post, okhttp, captcha

please I need help because I am getting captcha error when trying to make a POST request using okhttp.

Here is the sample response:

````
        <div class="cf-columns two">
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>
            <p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>
            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>
            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>
          </div>
        </div>```
````